# What difference does my choice of significant combat loss make?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've not played Mass Effect 1 or 2, and during character creation in Mass Effect 3 I'm asked to choose what experience of combat loss I have. This makes little sense to me, I don't know who the people mentioned are. What difference does it make to the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several decisions made during Mass Effect 1 and 2 have outcomes that affect the story in Mass Effect 3 -- in particular, it's entirely possible to finish Mass Effect 2 while losing almost your entire crew, including your party members.

This [Mass Effect Wiki page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Save_File_Transfer#Mass_Effect_.E2.86.92_Mass_Effect_2_.E2.86.92_Mass_Effect_3) contains a complete summary - or at least, we think it's mostly complete.

The "combat loss" it's alluding to is a shorthand way of asking whether you want a fabricated ME1/ME2 backstory where none, some, most or all of your crew survived.

It'll still assume suboptimal outcomes for various side missions and/or DLC that you never played, though; the only way to get those is to play through ME1 and ME2 yourself and complete them.

Comment: All of your crew survived is not an option.  You have to choose Ashley, Kaidan, or multiple losses.

Comment: Ah. Personally, I had a preserved 1->2->3 save lying around so I didn't run into the option.

Comment: Yeah, if you remember, you have to sacrifice either Kaiden or Ashley on Virmire in ME1, so at least one of them will be dead.

Comment: Yeah, I remember. It's been more than a few years, though.